# pass empty string when user does not input anything in @HtmlTextboxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.textboxfor

facing a problem i have a @HtmlTextboxFor when user doesnot insert anything it is returning  the error how to pass empty string or null if it left blank.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'FromDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime'

when user doesnot insert anything it pass a empty string or null as value otherwise the value inserted by User.

whats wrong with my code.

```
public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public string FromDate { get; set; }
        public string ToDate { get; set; }
    private tDbContext tDbContext;
    private IReportService reportService;
    public void ViewReportList(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        reportService = new ReportService(tDbContext);
        ReportList = reportService.GetReportsList(fromDate, toDate);
    }
    }
```

view

```
@model Req.ViewModels.ReportViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Print", FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "date-picker form-control"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "date-picker form-control"})
}
```

Index Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel reportViewModel,DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
        {
...
reportViewModel.ViewReportList(FromDate, ToDate);
                return View("Index", reportViewModel);
            }
```

Revised Code After Suggestion

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel reportViewModel)
            {
    ...
    reportViewModel.ViewReportList(reportViewModel.FromDate, reportViewModel.ToDate);
                    return View("Index", reportViewModel);
                }
```

ViewmOdel

```
public class ReportViewModel
        {
            public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
        private tDbContext tDbContext;
        private IReportService reportService;
        public void ViewReportList(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
        {
            reportService = new ReportService(tDbContext);
            ReportList = reportService.GetReportsList(fromDate, toDate);
        }
        }
```

now i am getting this error it is showing the error

> the best overloaded method match for
>   ViewReportList(System.DateTime,System.DateTime)

after changes.

Comment: It's still not clear where the error happens, can you add the stack trace and the code of `reportViewModel.ViewReportList` method?

Comment: if i left it blank it does not comes to the Index method for debugging.

Comment: @Miranda what's the date format of the date picker? Is it `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: @ekad Date Format is `dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'`

Comment: Why do you have parameters `DateTime FromDate` and `DateTime ToDate` when your model already contains those properties. Just delete the last 2 parameters from the method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke its giving me strange value ` {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` when i left it blank, while debugging.. and then its throw the error `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: Because that's the default value for `DateTime`. If you want to be able to pass back a `null` value, make the properties in your model `DateTime?` (nullable) NOT strings!. The second is because your using sql `datetime` when you need to use sql `datetime2` if you want the full range

Comment: @StephenMuecke getting Error cannot convert from System.DateTime? to System.DateTime while Defining `public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }`

Comment: @Miranda, You need to decide what you want to do. Do you want to allow nullable values in the database? If not the why are you allowing a user to enter a null (your property should have the `[Required]` attribute and use client side validation with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. And in the controller, check `ModelState.IsValid`. If its not, return the view so the user can correct it. If that's the case, use `DateTime` not `DateTime?`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually it is a search page where user can left these fields blank, the main problem is with my signature of the mehtod when i made all the changes `public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }` like this. it is showing the error the best overloaded method match for `ViewReportList(System.DateTime,System.DateTime)`
when i removed the Paramaeters DateTime FromDate, and call it like 
`reportViewModel.ViewReportList(reportViewModel.FromDate, reportViewModel.ToDate, )`

Comment: You can map a `DateTime?` to `DateTime` using `FromDate.GetValueOrDefault()` - which will return a the value if `FromDate` has one, or else `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` if its null.

Comment: @StephenMuecke have updated my question with revised code, please have a look.

Comment: @Miranda, You seem to mixing up some concepts. A view model only contains properties for display/editing it a view. It should not contain your `ViewReportList()` method - that belongs in a separate service. Next, what is the expected result is a user posts back `null` for the `FromDate` or `ToDate` (or for both) - are you assuming if `FromDate` is `null`, its uses `DateTime.MinValue` and if `ToDate` is `null` it uses `DateTime.MaxValue`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can i have an Example , i'll make those changes according to your answer. yeah i have call the service into the viewmodel, i'll make those changes . and will call it in controller.

Comment: @Miranda, Example of what? Until you confirm what your expecting to happen if the users posts back `null` values of either `FromDate` or `ToDate` or both its impossible to help you any further.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have made Fromdate is to be required and now i have to put Todate to be optional..

Comment: So what does a `null` value for `ToDate` mean with respect to your database query? - DtaeTime.Today, DateTime.MaxValue, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The string field FromDate in your VM will be initialized to the empty string anyways and does not seem to be the issue. The issue here is your POST method. The model binder is trying to convert the FromDate string to a datetime for the param and it is not optional according to the method signature.

If these params should be optional, you should specify by making the date params nullable:

```
public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel reportViewModel, DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate)
```

or providing a default value:

```
public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel reportViewModel, DateTime FromDate = DateTime.MinValue, DateTime ToDate = DateTime.MaxValue)
```

However, you already have dates in your viewmodel so these params are redundant.

My suggestion:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel reportViewModel)
{
    ...
    reportViewModel.ViewReportList(reportViewModel.FromDate, reportViewModel.ToDate);
    return View("Index", reportViewModel);
}
```

and change the VM itself to DateTimes:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }  // maybe make these nullable or set defaults?
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i have updated m code accrding to your suggestion but its giving me strange value ` 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` when i left it blank, while debugging.. and then its throw the error SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: Are any fields going to be optional? If so, then make them nullable. If not, then mark them as [Required] or set a default value so it doesnt error. 1/1/0001 is the default value of a datetime so that means it was not set anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try using default value

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "date-picker form-control",**Value=""**})